# find 30 minutes ago modified file in Solaris

Tags: solaris

i want to find 30 minutes ago modified file in solaris. i have written below command to find 1 day ago modified file.

```
find . -mtime 1 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

please help me to find out 30mins ago modified file. My server is solaris.

Comment: Exactly 30 min, older or newer? When you can't install other find versions or use other tools, you might need to calculate the date/time 30 minutes ago, touch a tmp file with that date and use find command with the -newer option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar question and answer on unix.stackexchange.com.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72861/delete-n-minutes-old-file-in-solaris

As Solaris' find command has no -mmin option, the article suggests to use the absolute time.

And there are some other solution helped by the usage of script language like perl.

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/69234-how-delete-files-30-min-older.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: this answer is very useful and no extra softwarw needs to be installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use "gfind" on later versions of Solaris.  It's GNU find and does have the "-mmin" option.